# Swing GUI doesn't accept accent characters

Tags: java, swing, encoding, diacritics

I'm faced with a weird issue. My Java application doesn't accept accented characters such as é, è or ê. The Swing component `JTextField` converts it into e. Furthermore, I cannot insert: ´

It's strange, because it doesn't work with the compiled and packaged application that is intended for distribution to users (JAR file). When I execute my application within Eclipse everything works fine: These characters become accepted.

I checked the used VM encoding on start-up. They were different. The packaged application uses Cp1252 and Eclipse starts it with "ISO-...". The system property "file.encoding" displayed the concerning encoding accordingly. So, I tried to switch the encodings in order to reproduce the issue in Eclipse or fix it in my application. But the result was the same as before.

Do you have any idea what's going on?

Comment: 1) *"
Cheers

PAX"*  That amounts to 4 lines of noise.  Leave it out in future. 2) Don't forget to add the Java tag. 3) If you add a tag, and it becomes the 'major tag' it is then unnecessary to add the word in the question title.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll remember it in future! Update: If I press the diacritic character followed by 'e' then keytyped event receives 'e' w/o the diacritic character.

Comment: I was about to suggest you post an SSCCE, but then I realized it would take only a handful of lines of code to reproduce the problem ..and I did not know how to produce accented characters in **any** app. either way.  I'm running Windows with an English based locale.  Can you tell me how I'd produce those characters in Notepad (or other default Windows software)?

Comment: The deletion isn't necessary. If you would like to insert the dead key, ´, then you could switch your windows key board settings to German layout (for instance). The key is on the '+' key of the American keyboard layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the issue wasn't caused by Java or any encoding setting. My application hooks all key events. There was one component that consumed the key event for "dead keys". That's why the editor component (or JTextField) didn't receive the key event from event dispatcher.

Comment: On linux this problem didn't occur. Possibly, the events become processed in a different order than on windows.

Comment: Glad you got got sorted, and thanks for reporting the solution.  :)

Comment: What component consumed the key event for "dead keys"?

Comment: @guteFee unfortunately, it's too long ago. I cannot remind any details about that.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug referenced in OpenJDK bug tracker about this issue with Swing: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8064448.